# what aws services should i use in this scenario?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, data-analysis

A company's data warehouse receives orders from multiple ordering systems. This data needs to be stored and sales commission needs to be paid based on the state's sales made. A mapping table is present which associates state to Sales manager. How would you implement such a solution? Which AWS services would you use?  What are the major design decisions you will take to ensure that a payment is accurately tracked?

Comment: Frankly, from the tiny bit of information you have provided, you could probably just use an Excel spreadsheet on a PC. If there is some reason why this wouldn't work, you should edit the question and include such details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a **database** to store the information, such as **Amazon RDS for MySQL**. It doesn't sound like the data volume or usage justifies a Data Warehouse solution like Amazon Redshift.

You'll also need to run some application logic somewhere, presumably on an **Amazon EC2** instance.

The design of the **application**, including ensuring that the "payment is accurately tracked", is totally your responsibility. AWS provides the infrastructure for such a system, but not the software application.